How to resolve ENVI Flaash ACC error
I am currently preprocessing aster radiance at sensor(level 1b) images which I downloaded as .tif files, and can be accessed via this link from Earthdata. These are radiometric and geometrically corrected images. Hence, after subsetting and layer stacking, I proceeded straight to flaash correction. ENVI typically expects aster files to be in the .hdf format, but mine was in tif.
This is my FLAASH setup:

I selected the input .tif radiance file and choose output reflectance filename in .tif, i created a folder in my current dir for flaash output files(also tried outputing to directly to this working directory).
sensor type: ASTER,
pixel size: 15m,
extracted date and time from earthdata metadata on pre-download page,
all other automatically filed fields left as they are, as i am fairly new to ENVI.

I have tried saving the .tif stacked aster files as .dat and using as input radiance file in flaash but still did not work.
I keep getting the error that reads:

Problem: The FLAASH program has exited with the following error
ACC error: convert7  end of input record encountered on file unit: 0;
ACC_CONVERT7 <( 9)> ACC_HYPER2 <( 784)> ENVI_ACC_EVENT <(3179)>
ENVI_FLAASH_PROCESS_MANAGER <( 274)> IDLRTMAIN <( 183)> $MAIN$ <(
0)>

as shown in the given image.
I have searched rigorously online across different forums and realized this error to be unique

